# Chrome extensions and blobs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which, via sockets, gets sent information it should display as a notification.

So far, in a simple scenario, I'm able to display a notification using an icon from my own extension as the iconUrl.

However, if I use the image sent over via socket, nothing happens. No error messages, just, nothing.

Here is the relevant code...

chrome extension:

```
//DISPLAYS NOTIFICATION
function notify(notification){
    //DEBUG STATEMENTS
    console.log("notification title: " + notification["title"]);

    var arrayBuff = notification["icon"];
    intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuff);
    blob = new Blob(intArray, {type: 'image/png'});

    var opt = {
      type: "basic",
      title: "Some Title",
      message: "Some Message",
//          iconUrl: window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) <-- NOTHING HAPPENS IF I USE THIS...
      iconUrl: "../img/icon48.png"
    }
    chrome.notifications.create("someid", opt, function(id){
            console.log("created notification: " + id); <-- Prints regarless of which iconUrl line I use in opt.
    });
}
```

FYI, here is how i'm sending over the notification object via sockets from my node.js server:

```
function send_notification_to_socket(user, notification, target){
    fs.readFile(notification.iconpath, function(err, buf){
            if(socketstore.get_socket_by_id(user)){
                    socket = socketstore.get_socket_by_id(user);
                    notification["icon"] = buf;
                    socket.emit('notification', notification);
            }else{
                    console.log("No socket for user " + user);
            }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

If I look at the output of `console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError)`, i get the following output:

```
chrome.runtime.lastError: [object Object] background.js:286
(anonymous function) background.js:286
(anonymous function) extensions::notifications:114
run extensions::lastError:97
(anonymous function) extensions::notifications:105
imageUtil.loadAllImages.oncomplete extensions::notifications:79
(anonymous function) extensions::imageUtil:64
```

Clicking through on the code of imageUtil:14, I see:

```
callbacks.onerror({ problem: 'could_not_load', path: path });
```

Comment: And if you check `chrome.runtime.lastError` within `notifications.create` callback, is there any error?

Comment: Err, sorry, `chrome.runtime.lastError.message`

Comment: `chrome.runtime.lastError: Unable to download all specified images.` I guess there is something wrong with the way i'm making the blob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake. The following:

```
 blob = new Blob(intArray, {type: 'image/png'});
```

should be instead:

```
 blob = new Blob( [intArray] , {type: 'image/png'});
```